# After uploading dataset, Commands: df.columns, df.info are not working. Columns names and Info are not showing properly

Tags: python

After uploading the dataset, using the df.columns, and df.info commands.    Columns names and info not showing properly on the page, so resolve this problem what is the solution?

*problem such as this-not set all words properly column-wise

<bound method DataFrame.info of       Restaurant ID           Restaurant Name  Country Code              City  
0           6317637          Le Petit Souffle           162       Makati City
1           6304287          Izakaya Kikufuji           162       Makati City
2           6300002    Heat - Edsa Shangri-La           162  Mandaluyong City
3           6318506                      Ooma           162  Mandaluyong City
4           6314302               Sambo Kojin           162  Mandaluyong City

Answer (score 0):

There is a potential solution to the problem. Your Pandas DataFrame encoding system might not be specified to UTF-8. In this case, you need to specify your Pandas DataFrame encoding system when using the 'read_csv' function. For example, to specify your
encoding system, you can use this code:

```
import pandas as pd

# read the dataset with UTF-8 encoding
df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', encoding='utf-8')

# display column names and information
print(df.columns)
print(df.info())
```

Correct encoding system specifying helps pandas to read and display DataFrame.